# `getAttributeText('attribute_code')` return `false` always

Tags: magento-1.9, product, attributes

when I am using this code `$product->getAttributeText('attribute_code');`

It always return `false` in one of my script.

**and if I do  below way then it return right value why ??**

```
$attr_option_val = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product')->getAttributeRawValue($productId, 'attribute_code');
$product->setData('attribute_code',$attr_option_val);
echo $product->getAttributeText('attribute_code');
```

Comment: what type of attribute is `attribute_code`. getAttributeText works only for select and multiselect attributes.

Comment: @Marius  its dropdown(select)

Comment: if you call `$product->getData('attribute_text')` do you get something?

Comment: @Marius not getting anything

Comment: that's why you don't get a text value either. where does $product come from?

Comment: @Marius actually I am using your easylife_switcher extension and using `$simpleProducts = $this->getCachedAllowedProducts();` method I am getting ` foreach ($simpleProducts as $product) ` in foreach loop

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on the comments...
If you are getting the product from a collection of simple products associated to the configurable product you need to add this in the `config.xml` of your module in order for your attribute to be picked up

```
<frontend>
    <product>
        <configurable>
            <child>
                <attributes>
                    <attribute_code />
                </attributes>
            </child>
        </configurable>
    </product>
<frontend>
```

and clear the cache.

Comment: yep. you need to add all custom attributes you need in that xml section.

Comment: its my mistake I have not seen your `config.xml` by the way thank you for that